Best practice regarding static library linking and project directory structure in C
I have a project in C, and due to the nature of the application I'm making I've decided to statically link libconfig into my final binary to minimize the external dependencies needed to use it. Before, I've only ever dynamically linked libraries by doing the standard method of just using flags pointing to /usr/lib and /usr/include, leaving my personal project directory structure untouched.
This time around however I've compiled the static libconfig.a and included it in my directory structure, and have the Makefile use that for linking, as well as the required header file for the library, placed in my include/ directory which contains header files for my projects source .c files. See:
project/
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── bin/
├── include/
│   ├── headerfile1.h
│   ├── headerfile2.h
│   └── libs
│       └── libconfig.h
├── lib/
│   └── libconfig.a
├── obj/
└── src
    ├── srcfile1.c
    └── srcfile2.c

I am worried that this is bad practice, and I'm wondering if there exists a more standard and elegant way to deal with what I'm trying to do, especially if in the future someone will try to compile this from source.

Unsure whether this is really on topic here... The main problem IMHO is that you have a mixed source-built directory containing an external tool. That means that 1/ you are tying your source code to a specific build chain and  2/ you will have to follow the version changes of libconfig. I can understand that it may make porting your code to a new machine using the same system, including the build chain easier, but what if you have to use it say on a FreeBSD system (assuming that you currently use Linux)?

You might consider the
Categorical Imperative: What would happen if everyone wanted to minimize their dependencies and put static builds and frozen headers of their dependencies into their packages? Anyway, you will supplying a package that cannot be built from source and what's the point in
making users compile some source? Better just supply your executable with libconfig statically linked
if you insist on it not being a dynamic dependency and you're happy to sever your program it from upstream libconfig.

@MikeKinghan Well this is essentially what I was wondering about. I was initially concerned about some users who'd want to build it from source which is why I provided the library lib and headers but I suppose that would be pointless if they can't actually build that from source themselves.


I have a project in C, and due to the nature of the application I'm making I've decided to statically link libconfig into my final binary to minimize the external dependencies needed to use it.

This is a thing that is sometimes done, most often in the form of statically linking all dependencies.
Another thing that seems more common is for a binary software distribution to be dynamically linked against private versions of shared libraries that it provides itself (including third-party libraries).  I don't like this much, personally, but it does have some advantages.
However, those are completely separate questions from how the project source is organized and what is included in it.

I'm wondering if there exists a more standard and elegant way to deal with what I'm trying to do, especially if in the future someone will try to compile this from source.

There are no standards for project and build system organization.  There are loose conventions at best.
One of the ways that some projects deal with third-party dependencies that they suspect others might have difficulty obtaining is to bundle source for those dependencies.  They will then set up their build system to build the dependency as well.  Sometimes they will have (and IMO, they always should have) an easy means for people to build against libraries provided by the system instead of using the bundled copy.  This is largely orthogonal to linking -- you can do either static or dynamic linking in conjunction with this.
Another way that projects deal with third-party dependencies, especially those that are readily available, is simply to document their dependencies, along with instructions for how to obtain them at need.

BUT if libconfig is the only dependency you're concerned about, then I think you're making much ado about nothing.  It is a widely distributed open source library, with a long history and still maintained, with curated versions available from all the most popular Linux distributions, and easy to build from source if needed.

libconfig is indeed my only dependency like you mentioned. I opted to just document manual build instructions for libconfig if someone really does want to compile the program from source. This seemed 'cleaner' than having a multi-source directory (or rather, just my source accompanied by a prebuilt static library).

Also, I'm unsure if I understand you correctly in reference to "Sometimes they will have  an easy means for people to build against libraries provided by the system." How can this be done if an external library like libconfig needs to be installed by the user?

@Zsargul, "libraries provided by the system" is meant to be distinguished from those bundled with your software.  If you use, say, apt or dnf to install a library, then the installed library is integrated with and provided by the system.  I suppose you could distinguish personal library installations as a third category, but in practice, the requirements for supporting these are not much different from the requirements for supporting system libraries.
